# Trying to remove \"id\":x from json string using regular expression in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, json

I have a JSON string that looks like `{\"heading\":\"Test\",\"id\":1}` and I want to wipe the ID data from the string.

I've tried `test.gsub(/\,\\"id\\"\:d+/, '')` but that's not working.

How best to achieve this?

Comment: regex? Really? You gotta be kidding me. What's wrong with `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you add your suggestion as an answer? With an example, please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sergio's JSON.parse is something you should consider. But baring that, those `\`'s you are seeing probably aren't really part of the string. That's just how irb is displaying it.

So `test.gsub(/,"id":\d+/, '')` should be what you want. (Also fixed a few other small bugs in the regex).

Comment: Thanks. The reason I rejected the JSON.parse approach is that I have a massive string with lots of ids scattered thru it and parsing that to a hash then looping through and manually removing the ids is by far and away a more complex solution.